# Can't run EndlessAdapterDemo App

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to look at the EndlessAdapter demo (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless), but I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError for the class com.commonsware.cwac.endless.demo.DemoAdapter. But, the class is clearly there! I didn't change any code at all, other than use the "Fix project setup" option on Eclipse.

I've looked everywhere and I can't find how to get rid of this error!

Here's a screenshot: http://grab.by/ikO6

If someone could give me a step-by-step solution to solve this, I'd appreciate it so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have the main project declared as an Android library project, and that the `demo/` sub-project has a reference to that Android library project.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! That helped fixed it!
I have a slightly different issue now. I'm using your EndlessAdapter library to create my own endless list. Basically I'm doing a search to a website and if there are more pages, then I do another HTTP get to get the next page of results.
However, the cacheInBackground() and appendCachedData() happen before my HTTP get is completed. The result is that the same result page gets displayed like 20 times... how do you recommend I fix this? I could implement my own Locks, but I figured there's probably a smarter way around this problem. Could you help?

Comment: Also, I'm new to StackOverflow, so in general, should I make that a completely new question, or should I just comment underneath like I did?

Comment: @skywalkerdude: "how do you recommend I fix this?" -- no clue. The `EndlessAdapter` concept is that you would issue the HTTP request from `cacheInBackground()`, not outside of it. I have no idea how to handle your particular scenario, other than `EndlessAdapter` is unlikely to be well-suited for it. "should I make that a completely new question" -- it is sufficiently far off-topic from the original question that a new question would probably have been preferable. Comment threads are mostly for Q&A on the original question and answer, for clarification, etc.

Comment: @skywalkerdude: "From your documentation on github, it seems that cacheInBackground() fetches data from the web on a background thread and appendCachedData() actually puts the data on the main UI thread." -- correct. "If that's the case, then how do I access the data..." -- store it somewhere temporarily, such as in a data member of the adapter or activity.

Answer (score 1):

Once check your android version with compatible adt plugin